# Codeigniter's active record ignoring everything after "/"

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, codeigniter

**Issue**

User inputs data like `a/b`

**code we use to save the data**

```
<?php
    $text = $this->input->post('user_input');
    $data = array('text'=>$text);
    $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
?>
```

**problem**

data which is saved in the database is `a/` nothing after `/` data after `/` is not saved in the db

**note**

db column size is not any issue since it is `varchar` and size `10`

Comment: Are you passing the `user input`  with an ajax call?

Comment: yes, in fact using angular js

Comment: Parsing the string containing a slash in a json response will cause problems. So you will need to escape the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/` in the permitted_uri_chars `config.php` file.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-/';
```